# ASP.NET MVC View ExecuteResult for another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

What is the equivalent of:

```
   this.View("ViewName").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
```

for showing a view which is in another controller.

I.e. how to replace `this.ControllerContext` by another controller's context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to share a view across controllers, why don't you use the *Shared* folder and put the view in there?